# add different widgets to each wxnotebook tab permanently in a txt file or sqlite

Tags: sqlite, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

Please how can I add permanently different widgets in the tabs and save them permanently

```
<html>
<pre>
import wx
tabs = []
with open('test.txt','r') as file:
    for element in file.readlines():
        tabs.append(element)

class TabPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, pageNum):
        self.parent = parent
        self.pageNum = pageNum
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

class DemoFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Notebook", size=(600,400))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.tab_num = len(tabs)

        self.notebook = wx.Notebook(panel)
        for tab in tabs:
            name = "Page " + str(tab)
            tab = TabPanel(self.notebook, 1)
            self.notebook.AddPage(tab, name)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Add Page")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.addPage)
        sizer.Add(btn)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()

    def addPage(self, event):
        self.tab_num += 1
        new_tab = TabPanel(self.notebook, self.tab_num)
        self.notebook.AddPage(new_tab, "Page %s" % self.tab_num)
        tabs.append(self.tab_num)
        print()

        with open('test.txt','a+') as file:
            file.write(str(self.tab_num))
            file.write('\n') 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = DemoFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
</pre>

</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by saying `add permanently`? You just need to create the controls and add them to a sizer. Check the different samples on the wxPython download link.

Comment: how you notice when you click add page . a page is generated and stored in a txt file and if the program is reopen or reload the new tab is still there. how can I add a widget to that tab page ? and when I close the program and open again all the info is still there "widgets"

Comment: so what you want is to run the program the first time, click the button, then save the layout on exit. Then when the program starts again this layout will be restored. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: If my description is true - create a function in your wxFrame-derived class to add the notebook pages or controls that is being previously done. Then when you start the program - call this function. And just save the number of controls/pages that needs to be created. The other idea is to look at the `open source RAD tool`, such as wxGlade or wxFB or any other ones.

Comment: you've got the idea.  I really don't know how to do it I found this piece of code and  I did some modifications but I really don't know how to continue I would really appreciate if you can write a little example. Thank you in advance.

Comment: +1 for suggesting wxGlade. Have a look at XRC (XML format, wxGlade can generate it, too) as a text format understood by wxPython to specify a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you started (sorry not readdly familiar with python):

```
class DemoFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tab_num = 1
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Notebook", size=(600,400))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        with open( "test.txt", "r" as file:
            self.tab_num = file.read()

        self.notebook = wx.Notebook(panel)
        for tab in [1..self.tab_num]:
            name = "Page " + str(tab)
            tab = TabPanel(self.notebook, 1)
            self.notebook.AddPage(tab, name)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Add Page")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.addPage)
        sizer.Add(btn)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()

    def addPage(self, event):
        self.tab_num += 1
        new_tab = TabPanel(self.notebook, self.tab_num)
        self.notebook.AddPage(new_tab, "Page %s" % self.tab_num)
        tabs.append(self.tab_num)
        print()

        with open('test.txt','a+') as file:
            file.write(str(self.tab_num))
            file.write('\n') 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = DemoFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```